# Is it OK to post, and how should we deal with, non-English (or partly non-English) answers intended for translation?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, editing, flagging

Questions in languages other than English, or which contain non-English text and translated text, have been discussed before on meta.

But what about answers that are written in other languages? How should we deal with them? If someone can translate them, can we keep them? Should we tell people not to post answers that aren't in English? If a non-English answer is translated, should the original text be retained, in case the translation is misleading or incorrect? Should users who have limited English proficiency be told not to post answers in both English and another language? (They might be doing so with the intention that someone more proficient will check their English.)

This question is partly inspired by [Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/users/25863/bruno-pereira)'s recent edit and comment to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145325/22949). But it's not limited to that one highly specific scenario. I'm asking a more general question--what is (or should be) our policy, for this entire continuum of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've avoided trying to spec out policy for this, because in my opinion there are far bigger issues to deal with. We rarely get questions or answers in different languages, and the few times I've caught a post that needed translation, it was translated by a community member shortly afterwards. The truth is we're fortunately enough to have a large community and a very active subset of that community that's bi-lingual.

We have a general policy that questions and answers should be in [en_US](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3225/is-it-prefered-to-use-english-us-spelling-to-english-uk). However, I like to give leeway to questions and answers in another language, some time to let them survive and hope someone in the community can translate it.